# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Error Message for Accounts With Same Information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, user-accounts

I have created a registration page that asks for certain information, such as e-mail, that should only occur once in my accounts database. If an account already exists in the database with the e-mail given in the form, I would like to redirect back to the registration page except with a message warning the user of the mistake. Currently, this is the method in my controller that handles registration requests:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterTutor(Tutor tutor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Tutor t in db.Tutors)
            {
                if (t.Email == tutor.Email)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("RegisterTutor"); //Send the user back to the registration page.
                    //What can I do here to send a message like "Email already registered" and display it on the registration page?
                }
            }

            tutor.Password = Cryptography.Encrypt(tutor.Password);
            db.Tutors.InsertOnSubmit(tutor);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RegisterTutor");
        }
    }
```

I have tried using the ViewBag to pass a message to the view but it did not work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what is happening here, you are creating a new request.  A RedirectTo Action instructs the browser to go and get another page.  when the redirecttoaction is hit the browser receives a 302 code and then goes and gets another page, in your case it goes to the registertutor action and gets the repsonse so anything you put even before the redirect to action or after it is effectely lost.

you have a couple of options,

you can use the tempdata to pass a message to the registertutor function which is kept for the next request so the view in registertutor could use the tempdata to get the message or some sort of caching system (more work i guess) on the server.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom validation in your ViewModel

```
public class User
    {

        [CheckEmail(ErrorMessage="Email Aready Exists")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property,
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class CheckEmail : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
           //below code is to check the email against the database values. I've used LINQ with Entity Framework. You can use your own way to check the database.
            DataClasses1DataContext dc=new DataClasses1DataContext();
            bool email = (from tbuser in dc.tblClients
                         where tbuser.Email == value.ToString()
                         select tbuser).Any();

            if (email)
            {
                return false;//return false if email exists
            }

            return true;//return true if email does not exists
        }
    }

Now this validation is fired when you call ModelState.IsValid in your controller.

    if (ModelState.IsValid)//Validation fires here
    { 

    }
```

Comment: I understand that this will be caught using ` ModelState.IsValid`, but this does not show any error message to the user.

Comment: Why not "Email Aready Exists" error message should be shown to the user